# How to update DLL files of production website without effecting active users

Tags: c#, web

We have web application website, which includes a bin folder that has all the DLL files. These Dll files is compilation of all backend codes built by Visio Studio. We have several production servers working as the app server. So every time when we do production update, we take one app server off from load balancer in order to not effect active user. After replace old files with new files, we bring the app server on to the load balancer. Then I do the same thing to the next server. Now I'm wondering if I do not use load balancer software to take app server off/enable, but just replace the DLL files to each server. Will that effect active users who is using the application website? Like kicking them out of website, or just lost all the data that they are typing in a form, something like that.

Comment: Your current steps seem to be reasonable... Copying files can't generally be done atomically, so your server will be in half-broken state while you update DLLs/pages.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you replace your DLLs with your code compilation you 'll be logout from the system.
This not happens when you just replaced a webform.